# redirect/echo if file.php?id=* not found/doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, row

Hey guys,
PHP and MySQL newguy here. Wrote this php file which display the content of a row relative to the ID stated in the URL ( eg row 3 is file.php?id=3 ), heres the source: http://pastie.org/1437017

If I goto an id to which the relative row does not exist (eg .php?id=99999999999999), what do I put to in to get it to redirect to another page or echo 'FAIL'. I though about using the if command, but couldn't figure out the syntax. I also looked around the web, but no avail.

Thanks guys

Comment: You need to check and see if your result set is empty.  IF your result set is empty THEN redirect.  Does that help?

Comment: **do not redirect** but issue a `Header( "HTTP/1.0 404 Not found");`

Comment: by using a function from my previous answer you can easily accomplish it. Do you ever read the answers?

Comment: I did indeed, please understand, I'm really new to PHP, just learning the easiest way to do things, thank you for your previous answer though :)

Comment: this function result already has everything you need. it's either array of data or empty array which can be easily checked with if() statement. I'd prefer a bit of understanding or a refining question rather than meaningless words of gratitude. as a result you've got a bunch of shitcode down below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following line:

```
$name=mysql_result($result,$id,"name");
```

If there is no row with the id `$id`, `$name` will be `false`.  You could therefore do the following:

```
if (!$name) {
    header('Location: http://yoururl.com');
    die();
}
```

Better yet would be to modify your query to this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM likes where id=$id";
```

and then do

```
if (!$num) {
    header('Location: http://yoururl.com');
    die();
}
```

where `$num` is the number of row returned, as set in your existing code.

---

**Edit** As noted elsewhere in this question, it is probably better to serve a `404 Not Found` page with appropriate content, rather than redirecting to another page.  I can just about imagine a situation where redirection is appropriate, but if your redirection page says "item not found", this is the wrong approach.

Comment: Redirecting is not appropriate. The page does not exists, so the HTTP status code should say so.

Comment: @Oswald **Probably** true, and I have added to my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd redesign your query to something *like*

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id;`

where $id is the $_GET value - sanitised of course.

if that query returns any results `(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)`

then you know a valid record has been found. If not, the id doesn't exist, so you can throw an error/redirect.

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_num_rows()](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) gives you the number of rows in your select, so if that value is 0, you know there isnt any row with that given id.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
    echo "There are no rows with this id";
}else{
     // Your normal code
}
```

Comment: Given the fact that the current query is `"SELECT * FROM likes"`, this method won't work unless the query is modified.